# Submit form with x-ray

Tags: javascript, node.js, x-ray

I just found a neat web scraper for node called [xray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray), is it possible to use this library to populate form data and submit it? Or is this library only for reading data from a webpage?

Comment: Reading through the docs and the source seems to indicate it's "read-only".